# Linq Entity Framework: select table data without repeated data into IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am working with the following technologies: C#, SQL Server, ASP.NET and Entity Framework and Linq.

I have a many-to-many relation in my database:

[image: my database diagram]

The model classes:

```
public class Courses
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //more properties here
     public student stud { get; set; }
}

public class inscribe
{
    [Key]
    public intId { get; set; }
    //properties here
    public student student{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("student")]
    public string StudentId{ get; set; }
    public Courses Courses{ get; set; }
}
```

Given a student Id, I would like to return a list of courses where he/she is inscribed.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
public IEnumerable<CursoDto> GetCursosAlumno(Int studentId)
{
     //some code here to validate
     var x = _dbContext
                 .Inscribe.Include(c => c.Courses)
                 .Where(c => c.StudentId == studentId).toList();
     // x variable is a list<inscribe>
}
```

My problem is that I do not know how to access to the courses entity and return it as a list, for instance:

```
var result = X.Courses;
return result; //result is a list<courses>
```

How can I do it? If possible, not using a foreach block please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Code First approach you don't need to add "link table" (`inscribe` in OP) into your models (it will be created transparently).

```
//Models
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //more properties here
     public virtual /*important*/ ICollection<Student> studs { get; set; }
 }
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //more properties here
     public virtual /*important*/ ICollection<Course> courses { get; set; }
 }

 //Controller
var stud = _dbContext.studs.Where(s => s.Id == /*param*/id).FirstOrDefault();
var courses = stud.courses.ToList();//Real courses with id, name, etc. No Include required
```

**Update**
If you do need the "link table" (for example to add some properties like `sortOrder` or `enrollmentDate`) then the models will be a little different.

```
//Models
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //more properties here
     public virtual /*important*/ ICollection<StudentCourse> studs { get; set; }
 }
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //more properties here
     public virtual /*important*/ ICollection<StudentCourse> courses { get; set; }
 }
[Table("inscribe")]
public class StudentCourse
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int StudentId {get; set'}
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CourseId {get; set'}
    //extra properties
    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public virtual Student stud { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public virtual Course course { get; set; }
}

//Controller
var courses = _dbContext.courses.Where(c/*c is "link"*/ => c.Student/*StudentCourse prop*/.Any(s/*link again*/ => s.StudentId == someId/*param*/));//again courses
```

As you see `Include` is not required.

Comment: hello, thanks for your advice . I have noticed that the code you are suggesting inside the controller misses the  inscribe table. Can you please update?thanks

Comment: thanks for the update, I have a question, when I use virtual property, I enable lazy loading, but can I implement your suggestion with eager loading?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = _dbContext
    .Inscribe.Include(c => c.Courses)
    .Where(c => c.StudentId == studentId)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Courses).ToList();
```

Comment: hello, I tried it but I receive an error: the type element for method....can not be infered from usage. Try specifying the arguments explicitly.
thanks